# Fps drop when playing games on wine

Tags: nvidia, graphics, wine, games, bug-reporting

I'm new to the Ubuntu world...

When I'm trying to play hot pursuit on Windows, *I have 60 fps in 1360x768 with high texture*, but when I'm playing in Ubuntu using wine, *I have 5 or 10 fps when selecting cars, and racing* (I think; can't see the fps) wih the same setting.

I've installed the latest driver from NVidia. In the system details, Ubuntu recognizes my graphics cards. I'm using *gt640 2gig from pixelview*. Is there anything wrong?
<>when In open empire earth 2, it says I'm using NVidia 8800gs or gt. I can't see it clearly.

I've surfed the net for 2 hours and still can't find any answer.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) No problem not being perfect in English, but there is something on your keyboard called a "Shift" key!  :P  ;-)

Comment: Hi Thanks :D. I'll try to use more of Shift key letter ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely the fact that it is run in wine. It should not make such a big drop in FPS but when you run something in wine it runs slower because it is not native, neither is it emulated. If you can go into the game settings and see what the game thinks your graphics card is.

Comment: To add to what @Dalton said, you may want to use PlayonLinux to run your game because it lets you easily install other dependencies that may make the game run faster.

Comment: ow thanks, i dont have big enough bandwith to download my games. So  im trying to play a preinstalled games on windows. And it doesnt work so well. thanks :D

the games thinks im using an nvidia 8800gt